# Can Meta change its accepted answer styling to UX?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, meta

This is what an accepted answer looks like on Meta:

[image: Visual Aid of Project]

**Isn't this hard to see on the eyes?**

Why not this:

[image: Visual Aid]

Comment: This [fails three of four accessibility standards](http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=4c9067&bcolor=e4f9d3). Should *definitely* be changed.

Comment: That said, apparently the UX model [fails all four of them](http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=ffffff&bcolor=4ab471)... maybe standards aren't always right.

Comment: @ArtOfCode You make a great point. I knew something was wrong without using special tech.

Comment: This question needs an answer from a moderator. What will it take for Stack Exchange to change its styling?

Comment: It'll take them accepting this feature request, and then a developer implementing it.

Comment: Am I the only person who finds the first screen shot much easier to read than the second?

Comment: @CødePlay It looks like they applied the change on most established SE sites sometime today.  No [status-completed] though...

Comment: We'll take a look into this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For a UX model pass, the color should change `#4ab471` and the text color needs to be changed to `#0a0a0a` to [pass everything](http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=0a0a0a&bcolor=4ab471).

The green looks very similar (and appealing) to the one in your second photo but the white color seems to be a little too light thus the failure @ArtOfCode mentioned. So the text has to change to a darker color, which will be `#0a0a0a` because of the need of dark text on a light background.

Comment: Excellent answer. Before I accept an answer, I want to wait for a moderator to answer.

Answer (score 2):

This has been changed somewhere in 2017 or 2018: compare [this Wayback Machine snapshot from November 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20171108113556/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) with [this one from November 2018](https://web.archive.org/web/20181111101105/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson).

Of course, everything looks different now with the new profile page:

[image]